# C# Discord Bot, trying to include an API for a command

Tags: c#, json, api, discord

I'm a novice programmer and I'm trying to put a small Discord bot together for a server. After spending a good hour or two trying to figure out how to use the API from https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api I have given up and have come to ask for help.

At the moment I'm using

```
public static async Task<string> GetRequest(string url)
    { 
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var obj = JObject.Parse(myContent);
                    var ret = (string)obj["joke"];
                    Console.WriteLine("joke: {0}", ret);
                    return ret;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is looking for content with the label "fact" when the joke API uses "joke"; you can't just use the same code across differing APIs, particularly when they have structured content like JSON.

Try changing

`var ret = (string)obj["fact"]`

to:

`var ret = (string)object["joke"]`

I would recommend you read: [What is JSON?](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) over at W3.

And be sure to always pay attention to the API documentation:

> Fetching a random joke as JSON:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://icanhazdadjoke.com/
{
  "id": "R7UfaahVfFd",
  "joke": "My dog used to chase people on a bike a lot. It got so bad I had to take his bike away.",
  "status": 200
}
```

You can see the JSON structure, and the "joke" field.

Comment: I did that when I tried just copy/pasting the code. [console output](https://i.gyazo.com/152387a61eebc8c655125dc06c48ff23.png)

Comment: @CasinoBoyale clearly that console output shows more code than you've shared, please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @CasinoBoyale additionally, please indicate what it is **precisely** that isn't working; based purely on the code you've shared, the field access is the problem.

Comment: [what detects the command](https://i.gyazo.com/0f216245e797e848d42e515b6eb17c8e.png) and  [what is done when the command is detected](https://i.gyazo.com/7db5d0f651ca844b3de488caf33773e8.png)

Comment: using [this](https://i.gyazo.com/dde7c05a454fa3610b5ef030280d5e61.png) 3 doesn't get output to the console.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger?